# PHP multidimensional array: append indexed multidimensional array based on var

Tags: php

I am using multidimensional arrays and am accessing them after using `explode` on a string. The resulting array should be nested with the number of occurrences of '.' in the given string. For instance, foo.bar.ok is ['foo']['bar']['ok'].

Currently, I am doing:

```
switch (count($_match)):
    case 1:
    $retVal = str_replace('{' . $match . '}', $$varName[$_match[0]], $retVal);
    break;
    case 2:
    $retVal = str_replace('{' . $match . '}', $$varName[$_match[0]][$_match[1]], $retVal);
    break;
    case 3:
    $retVal = str_replace('{' . $match . '}', $$varName[$_match[0]][$_match[1]][$_match[2]], $retVal);
    break;
endswitch;
```

Quintessentially I would like to have unlimited number of `$_match[x]` using a loop.

*Edit*
The resulting array should be in the format: $array[foo][bar][ok]

Here are some examples I tried:

```
$string = 'foo.bar.ok';
$exploded = explode('.', $string);
$bracketed = array_map(function($x) { return [$x]; }, $exploded);
echo "<pre>";var_dump($bracketed);
```

```
$bracketed = array_map(function($x) { return "['$x']"; }, $_match);
$result = implode('', $bracketed);
var_dump(eval('return $t' . $result . ';'));
```

The first doesn't append arrays in nested structure, it lists them as 0, 1, 2, etc and the second works but it uses eval.

Finally, using loops as suggested worked.

```
for ($replace = $$varName[$_match[0]], $i = 1; $i < count($_match); $i++) {
    if (isset($replace[$_match[$i]]))
        $replace = $replace[$_match[$i]];
    }
    if (is_string($replace) || is_numeric($replace))
        $retVal = str_replace('{' . $match . '}', $replace, $retVal);
```

I would like to see a working array_walk example though? - thank you!

Comment: Please provide at least one example of what the `$_match` array will contain. Also, it's hard to determine what you're trying to do because your `for()` code does not do the same thing as your initial `switch()` code. The `switch()` code does a single `str_replace()` while the `for()` loop does multiple `str_replace()`, and also has checks for `is_string()` and `is_numeric()`. In any case, why don't you try the `array_walk()` method yourself and post the results if you have problems?

Comment: It's ok, I think the for loop is ok. The context is quite complicated the code is just an extract. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to perform `$$varName[$_match[0]][$_match[1]][$_match[2]...[$_match[count($_match)-1]`?

```php
for ($var_name = $varName[$_match[0]], $i=1; $i<count($_match); $i++) {
  $var_name = $var_name[$_match[$i]];
}
$retVal = str_replace('{' . $match . '}', $$var_name, $retVal);
```

This could probably be improved by replacing the `for()` with `array_walk()`.

Comment: But $var_name would equal $var_name[$_match[2]]; not nested arrays as expected. Maybe I don't see something??

Comment: @youdsmedia Please edit your question to provide an example value for `$_match` so that we can duplicate the intended output.

Comment: Using this loop solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_map()` and `implode()`.

```
$string = 'foo.bar.ok';
$exploded = explode('.', $string);
$bracketed = array_map(function($x) { return "[$x]"; }, $exploded);
$result = implode('', $bracketed);
```

Comment: Ahh array_walk. Of course. The issue here was returning the array in a method call does not cause this behaviour. However, this does so hurrah. Many thanks.

Comment: sorry, got stuck again. $result returns [foo][bar][ok] but there is no array for me to use in PHP syntax. Doing eval('echo $t' . $result . ';'); works but this is a very strange approach? What am I missing?

Comment: What arrray are you talking about? If you have an array of `foo.bar.ok`-type strings you can execute this code in a `foreach` loop, `array_map()`, etc.

Comment: All sorted now, see main post thanks.